# Como saber a versão do JSP que está em um projeto

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho um projeto `Java` e gostaria de saber qual a versão do `JSP` que está sendo usada nesse projeto. Exemplo, tenho um projeto antigo, como consigo obter essa informação?

Comment: http://www.guj.com.br/java/14410-versao-do-jsp-e-servlet---como-saber

Comment: Deve existir alguma opção nas propriedade do projeto que mostre isso, já fuçou lá? Mas espeto que esse link ajude. http://www.guj.com.br/java/14410-versao-do-jsp-e-servlet---como-saber

Comment: Tudo depende. Quando você diz *projeto*, está dizendo um projeto do Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ, Maven? Ou seria um sistema executando em algum servidor de aplicação? Não é incomum projetos cuja configuração de compilação usa uma versão da API e outra no ambiente de execução. Se atente a isso e, se possível, edite sua pergunta e acrescente mais detalhes sobre a sua situação.

Comment: É um projeto Eclipse com Ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um JSP e coloque lá o seguinte código:

Versão container servlet:

```
<%= application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %>
```

Versão JSP:

```
<%= JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion() %>
```